# Only getting one of the weight in flash file, how to go about

Tags: sifr

first time using the latest build,

here's what i have, i have bold, heavy, lighht and italic in the flash file how do i call them in the script

i'd like to make to h1#logo use the bold weight.

```
sIFR.replace(gotham, {
  selector: 'h1#logo',
  css: [
      '.sIFR-root { font-size:44px; font-weight:Bold; color:#17140c; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 !important;'
      ]

  ,filters: {
        DropShadow: {
           distance: 1
          ,color: '#f5f5f5'
          ,strength: 3
          ,alpha: .5
          ,blurX: 0
          ,blurY: 0

        }
      }
   ,wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Flash can be picky, did you try `font-weight: bold` (lowercase "b")? If there are different variants of the font family for the different weights ("Helvetica Bold" for example) you may need to explicitly state that font family if you've embedded more than one.